# Trying to make this webcrawler print a specific song depending on the users input

Tags: python, function, input, beautifulsoup, request

Trying to make this web crawler ask the user for a position of a song from the top charts and then print that song, position etc. I've been able to do all of this but the position is always one more. For example, if you asked for the 2nd top song of the week, it would give you the third.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

lol = input("Number: ")

if lol == "1":

    url = 'https://www.officialcharts.com/charts/singles-chart/'
    req = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')

    print("")
    print("TYPE THE POSITION")
    user_pos = int(input("Please pick a number between 1 - 100: "))
    if 1 <= user_pos <= 100:
        hit = soup.find_all("div", class_="title-artist")[user_pos - 1]
        title, artist = [hr.text for hr in hit.findAll("a")]
        print("POSITION | TITLE | ARTISTS")
        print(user_pos, "|", title, "|", artist)
    else:
        print("Next time pick a number between 1 and 100")
```

Comment: Maybe `hit = soup.find_all("div", class_="title-artist")[user_pos - 1]` will fix that?

Comment: so, why is the variable called "lol"?

Answer (score 0):

It's because of he indexing. When you want to get very first element, you have to call `soup.find_all("div", class_="title-artist")[user_pos - 1]`. `soup.find_all()` returns a `list`. Indexing starts from 0.